# aspx menuItem linking

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have multiple aspx pages that use masterpage. (works fine)
now I want to add inside each aspx that links to the main masterpage another menu.

e.g. each aspx will have another unique menu.

I created a unique menu items e.g.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
  <Items>
   <asp:MenuItem Text="page1" Value="page1" NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
   <asp:MenuItem Text="page2" Value="page2" NavigateUrl="~/page2.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

same aspx page will have a container where the content will show

```
    <div id="output"></div>
```

so when the menu is clicked the result from NavigateUrl is populated into the div

how do I join them together?

thanks,

Comment: One way is using querystring, pass value in parameter, later retrieve value.

Comment: example or a link to the example would be appreciated. thx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    <asp:MenuItem Text="page1" Value="page1" 
NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx?value1=abc&value2=pqr"></asp:MenuItem>
```

**Code Behind**:
page1.aspx

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   String getFirstValue = Request.QueryString["value1"];
   String getSecondValue = Request.QueryString["LastName"];
}
```

Here these string variable retrieve values from querystring

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of different menus you need, you could put a dozen different menus into your master page, each with visible = false.

Then, each Page1.aspx.cs Page_Load turns on the visibility for the menu it is supposed to display.

Comment: I want to put the different menus into aspx pages not in the master page (the masterpage contains the main menu), each aspx has its own layout and layout and a place where to put its own another menu.

Answer (score 0):

How about a different approach.  Instead of using a menu to navigate to standalone .aspx pages, and trying to get those into the div, how about using [.ascx UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead?

UserControls let you reuse that same chunk of a page on any number of other pages.  Again, you can put a dozen of them on a page and make them all invisible.  Then you could use buttons or radiobuttons to control the visibility of the ascx controls.

Just a suggestion.